# Python3 does not truncate the decimals of automatically like python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting, integer, truncate

In python2, if you did

```
n = 12
n /= 10
```

n would become 1.

In python 2,
the above would cause n to be 1.2, even if it were passed in an integer parameter like

```
def foo(self, n: int) -> bool:
        print (n / 10)
        return True
```

The simple fix is to just cast it to an integer like so:

```
n = int(n/10)
```

But this is quite memory/time costly. Are there better alternatives in python3?

Comment: You can achieve same effect as python2 with `//` operator. `n = n // 10` or `n //= 10`

Comment: In Python 3 `/` is float division (called "true division") and `//` forces integer division

Comment: try to use `12//10`

Answer (score 0):

// is integer division, so it removes the decimal from the result.